# Looping with between()

Tags: r

I sort through photos marking the starting and ending images of photo groups containing animals of interest.  The finished product look something like whats included below. After sorting, I'd normally use the starting and ending  photos as markers to move photos of interest from each subfolder into a main folder for later processing.

```
Primary.Folder     |   Sub.folder |Start.Image..         |End.Image.. 

   RPU_03262019_05092019 | 100EK113 | 2019-03-26-11-23-46 | 2019-03-26-11-32-02          
   RPU_03262019_05092019 | 100EK113 | 2019-03-27-08-35-00 | 2019-03-27-08-35-00                
   RPU_03262019_05092019 | 101EK113 | 2019-03-31-00-29-58 | 2019-03-31-00-59-58                
   RPU_03262019_05092019 | 101EK113 | 2019-03-31-01-44-58 | 2019-03-31-01-59-58                
   RPU_03262019_05092019 | 101EK113 | 2019-03-31-03-14-58 | 2019-03-31-03-44-58                
   RPU_03262019_05092019 | 101EK113 | 2019-03-31-04-34-58 | 2019-03-31-04-39-58                
   RPU_03262019_05092019 | 101EK113 | 2019-03-31-05-04-58 | 2019-03-31-05-14-58                
   RPU_03262019_05092019 | 101EK113 | 2019-03-31-05-44-58 | 2019-03-31-05-44-58                
   RPU_03262019_05092019 | 101EK113 | 2019-03-31-19-30-58 | 2019-03-31-19-40-58
```

By having a list of the total images I'm hoping to loop my way through each row and build a new list of photos of just animal subjects that I can file.copy into another folder. I'm hoping between can help with this.

So far I've removed the .JPG from every file in the total photo list to match whats in the sorted csv, separated Start.Image.. column to t1 and End.Image.. column to t2, and tested a for loop to see if they line up.

```
fn <- photolist %>% str_replace_all('\\.JPG', '')
t1 <- csvfilled[,4]
t2 <- csvfilled[,5]

#test
for (i in t1) for (j in t2) {
  print(paste(i,j,sep=","))
  }

# using between() function
for (i in t1) {
  for (j in t2){
  finalsortedlist<- (fn[between(fn,i, j)])
    } 
}
```

The test results show i and j are running at the same time. It appears i waits for j to loop through before it continues at which j loops again.

```
 "2019-05-09-09-24-24, 2019-05-08-18-35-24"
 "2019-05-09-09-24-24, 2019-05-08-19-05-24"
 "2019-05-09-09-24-24, 2019-05-08-19-50-24"
 "2019-05-09-09-24-24, 2019-05-09-00-09-24"
 "2019-05-09-09-24-24, 2019-05-09-09-59-24"
 "2019-05-09-09-24-24, 2019-05-09-10-49-24"
```

Is there a way to run them in sequence like below?

```
"2019-03-26-11-23-46, 2019-03-26-11-32-02"          
"2019-03-27-08-35-00, 2019-03-27-08-35-00"                
"2019-03-31-00-29-58, 2019-03-31-00-59-58"                
"2019-03-31-01-44-58, 2019-03-31-01-59-58"                
"2019-03-31-03-14-58, 2019-03-31-03-44-58"                
"2019-03-31-04-34-58, 2019-03-31-04-39-58"                
"2019-03-31-05-04-58, 2019-03-31-05-14-58"                
"2019-03-31-05-44-58, 2019-03-31-05-44-58"               
"2019-03-31-19-30-58, 2019-03-31-19-40-58"
```

I basically want:

```
"1,1"
"2,2"
"3,3"
"4,4"
```

instead of

```
"1,1"
"1,2"
"1,3"
"1,4" 
"2,1"
"2,2"
"2,3"
"2,4"
```

Comment: Once I have this down the between() part should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be fairly simple using 'map2' from the purrr library.

```
finalsortedlist <- map2(t1, t2, ~fn[between(fn, .x, .y)])
```

Essentially, map2 will take the nth item from both t1 and t2, and pass them as .x and .y respectively to your function. The result will be a list containing the results for every iteration.

Comment: Is there a way to consolidate the dates into one vector?  Next step is running file.copy and I'm unsure how to approach it with a list.

Comment: @BrandonMayer, do you mind showing me what the first few elements of the resulting list look like?